# How to exit 2D game simulation (only) without exiting the Java code?

Tags: java, game-development

I (new to Java) am working on a decades old Java project built using Golden T Studios Game dev jdk. I have a game in the project which runs a 2D simulation. The code structure in a nutshell is as follows:

```
package game;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

import com.golden.gamedev.GameLoader;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import sometcpimports.*;

public class MainGAME extends JFrame implements Runnable {

    public static void main(String[] args) { //call new MainGAME;
    }

    public MainGAME() {//initiate game parameters; 
    //start new THREAD; 
    }

   @Override
   public void run() { //initiate new game and environment;
    game = new GameLoader();
    gameenv = new GameEnvironment(params); //This class is in another file "public class GameEnvironment extends Game {}" 
    //I don't clearly undertsand what the following lines do, so I'm mentioning them as is;

    game.setup(gameenv, dimensions);
    this.setVisible(false);
    gameenv.setVisible(false);
    game.start();
    game.setVisible(true);

    //tbd (code reaches this step)

    }
}
```

My goal is to run the above simulation multiple times (with different inputs each time) and extract information after each run in a new main class as follows.

```
public class gamedriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MainGAME.params = some params;
        MainGAME.main(); // runs the simulation;

        //tbd1 (code doesn't reach this step)
    }
}
```

The issue is that, on running the simulation from a different file (new main class), I am unable to exit 2D simulator after one run. The code doesn't reach `//tbd1` in the new main class which has some output print statements. Essentially I want to simply exit simulator and not the whole JVM. So far I've tried:

1. `game.stop()` & `gameenv.finish()` at `//tbd` which does nothing.
2. `System.exit(0)` at `//tbd` which exits game after simulation but also exits jvm and doesnt reach the other main class.
3. `finish()` at both `//tbd` and GameEnvironment class which behaves exactly like point 2.

Additionally, I am unable to run the above (MainGAME in gamedriver class) in a for loop. This throws `Game.Exception error`. I understand it has something to do with threads but I'm not sure how to run them.

Thank you for your time. Appreciate your help!

Comment: Are you sure you need what you say you need? All you want it to print some stuff right after your MainGame class runs, correct? If that's so, you're severely overthinking the problem. Why do you think you need a second class to run the first class in order to dump some information on the screen?

Comment: Hi MarsAtomic, Thank you for the read. Sorry, the actual problem is to run an optimisation code on top of the game. This is just a test to check if I am getting my desired variables from the game. Once I am done, I will simply import my optimisation code in the gamedriver and run it (iterate the game).

Comment: So... you have three options here: 1) Run your code in a debugger, set breakpoints after the values you want to see have been set and inspect your variables using the debugger; 2) Learn to use JUnit and write a test with some asserts that test the variables in question; or 3) drop some simple System.out.println() statements after the variables have been set and print the variables to console. You're really making this a lot harder than it needs to be because you're fixated on a particular approach. The problem has nothing to do with drivers or threads.

Comment: Thank you! I will try these out.

Answer (score 0):

I found a method to solve the above problem. I'm posting my workaround as a reference for someone who encounters a similar issue. Please note that there might be other (better) solutions out there.

1. I disabled all (any) threads implementation in the MainGAME (by simply commenting it out).
2. I added `System.out.println()` in MainGAME to print all my outputs at the end of simulation.
3. My second script uses Runtime processes to execute MainGAME:

```
public class gamedriver {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String separator = System.getProperty("file.separator");
            String classpath = System.getProperty("java.class.path");
            String path = System.getProperty("java.home") + separator + "bin" + separator + "java";
            String[] command = new String[]{path, "-cp", classpath, gamedriver.GAME.class.getName(), "output.csv"};
            Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
            process.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static class GAME {

        public static void main(String args[]) {
            PrintStream out = null;
            try {
                out = new PrintStream(args[1]); 
            } catch (FileNotFoundException p) {
                p.printStackTrace();
            }

            System.setOut(out);// this catches all output from the game to a csv file (output.csv)
            MainGAME temp = new MainGame(some params); // initiate the simulation
            temp.run()
            out.close();
            System.exit(0); // force close the simulator
        }
    }
}
```

4. I parse output.csv to get the solution.

This might be a sloppy way to solve the issue, but it worked for me, especially because none of the other methods provided by GTGE worked.